# what happens if I reset a unique_ptr with a shared_ptr pointing to it?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I would be surprised if this is not answered somewhere already. But I have not found it.

Anyway, as the question says I want to know what happens if I create a shared pointer from a unique pointer. I saw some suggestions from [here](https://github.com/lefticus/cppbestpractices/blob/master/08-Considering_Performance.md):

```
// Factor that returns unique_ptr
std::unique_ptr<ModelObject_Impl> factory();

// Store a shared_ptr to that returned unique_ptr
auto shared = std::shared_ptr<ModelObject_Impl>(factory());
```

Which got me thinking if I did something similar - where I have an owning-object that has a function that returns some internal object by unique_ptr - and I make a shared_ptr out of it (perhaps as suggested in the link). Then later if that owning-object destroys / resets its internal object - then what happens to my shared_ptr to it?

I know this is not quite what the link is suggesting to do - but I am not quite sure if this is a "good practise" or "undefined behaviour" - as far as I can tell, this would result in a dangling shared_ptr...

Comment: "*I have an owning-object that has a function that returns some internal object by unique_ptr ... if that owning-object*" This is a contradiction. If object X owns object Y, and it returns a unique_ptr to Y, it *no longer owns Y*. That is what it means to return a unique_ptr to something.

Comment: I would say that if your code ends up with the same memory address wrapped in both kinds of smart pointers at the same time, your code is faulty. The smart pointer is the owner and the same location can only have one owner.

Comment: @NicolBolas ah, so, I think you are saying this is "a bad idea" - in that usually, if you had to do this you might pass back a `const &` or just a raw pointer?

Comment: @code_fodder: It's neither a good nor bad idea; it is *impossible*, not without returning a naked pointer or something.

Comment: Its on the same level as putting your raw pointer into a smart pointer and then freeing/deleting it manually.

Comment: @PaulG. ah, yeah , I think I get it now! - it's daft : )

Comment: @NicolBolas "impossible" makes it sound like it would never happen, but as long as you still use raw pointers as non-owning pointers it's not that hard of a mistake to make. It's just semantically wrong to have multiple owners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where I have an owning-object that has a function that returns some internal object by unique_ptr - and I make a shared_ptr out of it (perhaps as suggested in the link). Then later if that owning-object

Stop. You have contradicted yourself. If object X owns object Y, and it returns a unique_ptr to Y, it *no longer owns Y*. That is what it means to return a unique_ptr to something.

If it returned a reference to a `unique_ptr`, well it doesn't matter because you either moved from it into your `shared_ptr` (in which case again, X no longer owns it), or you didn't, in which case *you* don't own it. Either way, ownership is unique.

To create a `shared_ptr` from a `unique_ptr` means that the `shared_ptr` claims ownership over the object. The `unique_ptr` no longer has it afterwards. That's why it takes an rvalue-reference to a `unique_ptr`; you have to move *into* the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: For my own sanity I tried to do it - I could not (as you predicted) - well, I could by returning a member unique_ptr with std::move - but that just passed ownership out of the "owning-object". Great answer, to a somewhat daft question thanks : )

Comment: @code_fodder • not a daft question; ownership and how smart pointers affect ownership is a tricky thing to wrap one's head around.